# WPS Chaining problem vec:Clip with vec:Reproject

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, wps

I want to execute GeoServer WPS process `vec:Clip` with `vec:Reproject`.
Here's the request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0.0" service="WPS" mlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>vec:Reproject</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS">
            <ows:Identifier>vec:Clip</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:DataInputs>
              <wps:Input>
                <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
                <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
                  <wps:Body>
                    <wfs:GetFeature xmlns:rv="it.veneto.regione.idt" service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2">
                      <wfs:Query typeName="rv:c0506111_ccs2007splus"/>
                    </wfs:GetFeature>
                  </wps:Body>
                </wps:Reference>
              </wps:Input>
              <wps:Input>
                <ows:Identifier>clip</ows:Identifier>
                <wps:Data>
                  <wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/json"><![CDATA[{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[1735624.32,5137289.81],[1735621.03,5137260.51],[1735621.32,5137215.02],[1735621.47,5137140.38],[1735613.9,5137063.64],[1735627.66,5137043.08],[1735652.05,5137001.73],[1735630.27,5136925.48],[1735622.09,5136887.96],[1735609.37,5136827.3],[1735602.11,5136808.69],[1735587.1,5136788.7],[1735548.39,5136748.86],[1735536.14,5136733.8],[1735533.48,5136717.11],[1735537.91,5136658.54],[1735539.29,5136609.17],[1735534.32,5136581.31],[1735502.44,5136523.92],[1735490.42,5136495.53],[1735436.28,5136399.54],[1735424.87,5136373.55],[1735420.2,5136352],[1735360.6,5136234.35],[1735395.43,5136200.9],[1735414.01,5136174.04],[1735428.29,5136141.35],[1735433.98,5136118.22],[1735441.67,5136058.33],[1735470.01,5136006.3],[1735527.75,5135909.37],[1735600.88,5135858.37],[1735624.22,5135841.29],[1735669.52,5135814.87],[1735774.99,5135794.59],[1735810.78,5135769.03],[1735857.1,5135739.56],[1735871.94,5135720.26],[1735870.97,5135712.34],[1735885.21,5135690.64],[1735889.04,5135671.3],[1735918.93,5135650.78],[1735981.28,5135628.02],[1736026.27,5135595.31],[1736056.72,5135577.98],[1736134.6,5135557.96],[1736177.46,5135553.35],[1736243.51,5135554.44],[1736274.95,5135555.24],[1736345.49,5135580.23],[1736552.85,5135451.43]]]]}]]></wps:ComplexData>
                </wps:Data>
              </wps:Input>
            </wps:DataInputs>
            <wps:ResponseForm>
              <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0">
                <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
              </wps:RawDataOutput>
            </wps:ResponseForm>
          </wps:Execute>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>forcedCRS</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>EPSG:3003</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>targetCRS</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>EPSG:3857</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/zip">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

In Geoserver I have this error:

```
14 Nov 12:11:33 DEBUG [org.vfny.geoserver.requests] - First 4 bytes of XML doc are : 3C ('<') 3F ('?') 78 ('x') 6D ('m')
14 Nov 12:11:33 DEBUG [org.vfny.geoserver.requests] - Charset detection phase 1. Inferred encoding: UTF-8
14 Nov 12:11:33 DEBUG [org.vfny.geoserver.requests] - Charset detection phase 2. Charset in XML declaration is `UTF-8`.
14 Nov 12:11:33 DEBUG [org.vfny.geoserver.requests] - Trying to create reader basing on existing charset information: `UTF-8`.
14 Nov 12:11:33 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Raw XML request starts with: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
    xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
    <ows:Identifier>vec:Reproject</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:DataInputs>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
                <wps:Body>
                    <wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS">
                        <ows:Identifier>vec:Clip</ows:Identifier>
                        <wps:DataInputs>
                            <wps:Input>
                                <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
                                <wps:Reference mi...
14 Nov 12:11:33 INFO [org.geoserver.wps] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
14 Nov 12:11:33 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wps.resource] - Associating process with execution id: 77dc36af-91b9-48c3-b2c4-a7e46180ad9e
14 Nov 12:11:33 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wps] - Saving status ExecutionStatus [processName=vec:Reproject, executionId=77dc36af-91b9-48c3-b2c4-a7e46180ad9e, asynchronous=false, phase=QUEUED, progress=0.0, userName=anonymous, creationTime=Wed Nov 14 12:11:33 CET 2018, completionTime=null, lastUpdated=Wed Nov 14 12:11:33 CET 2018, task=null, exception=null, nodeId=geoserver.staging]
14 Nov 12:11:33 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wps] - Saving status ExecutionStatus [processName=vec:Reproject, executionId=77dc36af-91b9-48c3-b2c4-a7e46180ad9e, asynchronous=false, phase=RUNNING, progress=0.0, userName=anonymous, creationTime=Wed Nov 14 12:11:33 CET 2018, completionTime=null, lastUpdated=Wed Nov 14 12:11:33 CET 2018, task=null, exception=null, nodeId=geoserver.staging]
14 Nov 12:11:33 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wps] - Saving status ExecutionStatus [processName=vec:Reproject, executionId=77dc36af-91b9-48c3-b2c4-a7e46180ad9e, asynchronous=false, phase=FAILED, progress=0.0, userName=anonymous, creationTime=Wed Nov 14 12:11:33 CET 2018, completionTime=Wed Nov 14 12:11:33 CET 2018, lastUpdated=Wed Nov 14 12:11:33 CET 2018, task=null, exception=java.lang.ClassCastException: net.opengis.wps10.impl.ExecuteTypeImpl cannot be cast to net.opengis.wfs.GetFeatureType, nodeId=geoserver.staging]
14 Nov 12:11:33 ERROR [org.geoserver.wps.executor] - Process execution failed
org.geoserver.wps.WPSException: Failed to retrieve value for input features
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.LazyInputMap.parseInputs(LazyInputMap.java:94)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.LazyInputMap.get(LazyInputMap.java:50)
    at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.buildProcessArguments(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:659)
    at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:544)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.ProcessStartupFilter$ProcessStartupWrapper.execute(ProcessStartupFilter.java:51)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:201)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.opengis.wps10.impl.ExecuteTypeImpl cannot be cast to net.opengis.wfs.GetFeatureType
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.InternalWFSInputProvider.getValueInternal(InternalWFSInputProvider.java:41)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.AbstractInputProvider.getValue(AbstractInputProvider.java:97)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.LazyInputMap.parseInputs(LazyInputMap.java:86)
    ... 10 more
```

Did I make a mistake in the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I solved the problem, there was a wrong mimetype.This is a working request WPS example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
<ows:Identifier>vec:Reproject</ows:Identifier>
<wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
        <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wps" method="POST">
            <wps:Body>
                <wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS">
                    <ows:Identifier>vec:Clip</ows:Identifier>
                    <wps:DataInputs>
                        <wps:Input>
                            <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
                            <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
                                <wps:Body>
                                    <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:rv="it.veneto.regione.idt">
                                        <wfs:Query typeName="rv:c1105223_pz" />
                                    </wfs:GetFeature>
                                </wps:Body>
                            </wps:Reference>
                        </wps:Input>
                        <wps:Input>
                            <ows:Identifier>clip</ows:Identifier>
                            <wps:Data>
                                <wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/json"><![CDATA[{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[1724379.86,5091390.61],[1724395.69,5091386.42],[1724410.59,5091383.39],[1724422.46,5091378.97],[1724435.27,5091370.59],[1724446.44,5091359.88]]]]}]]></wps:ComplexData>
                            </wps:Data>
                        </wps:Input>
                    </wps:DataInputs>
                    <wps:ResponseForm>
                  <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0">
                    <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
                  </wps:RawDataOutput>
                </wps:ResponseForm>
                </wps:Execute>
            </wps:Body>
        </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier>targetCRS</ows:Identifier>
        <wps:Data>
            <wps:LiteralData>EPSG:4326</wps:LiteralData>
        </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
</wps:DataInputs>
<wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/zip">
        <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
</wps:ResponseForm>
```

Answer (score 1):

The chained request should be posted to the internal WPS, not the internal WFS, the href attribute of that input should point to "http://geoserver/wps".